# Image upload and delete to Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, client-side, uploadify

I have uploaded image to amazon s3 using the site below :

http://www.flynsarmy.com/2011/03/upload-to-amazon-s3-with-uploadify/

Now i need to do

1. Delete (already uploaded) Image from s3
2. Convert original image to thumbnail and need to upload both original and thumbnail image to S3

These two things should be from client side as the above tutorial.. 
Any one please help me to find the solution?